# what is the minimum distance measurable with gps, minimum distance between 2 moving points

Tags: gps

I have 2 movable points. When the distance between them exceeds 10 ft, I want to get an alert. Is this possible? What is the minimum distance that is measurable?

Comment: You can get sub-centimeter accuracy with RTK. With ordinary DGPS services that you have to pay for you can get around 10 cm accuracy. For non-premium DGPS you can get around 0.5-1.0 m accuracy. These values are for somewhat expensive GPS units.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://www.gps.gov/systems/gps/performance/accuracy/) will help you further.

> How accurate is GPS?
>   It depends. GPS satellites broadcast their signals in space with a certain accuracy, but what you receive depends on additional factors, including satellite geometry, signal blockage, atmospheric conditions, and receiver design features/quality.
>   For example, GPS-enabled smartphones are typically accurate to within a 4.9 m (16 ft.) radius under open sky (VIEW SOURCE AT ION.ORG). However, their accuracy worsens near buildings, bridges, and trees.